# Can't send message to local root

Tags: debian, email, postfix

i have any problems with mit OpenMediaVault(ARM) based on Debian Stretch on my Raspberrypi 3B+ machine.

The following commands returns no error and no mails:

```sh
root@raspberrypi:~# echo "Content" | mail -s "Subject" root
root@raspberrypi:~# mail
No mail for root
root@raspberrypi:~# cat /var/spool/mail/root
root@raspberrypi:~#
```

---

Log from mail

```sh
cat /var/log/mail.log
```

```
Jul 13 08:12:16 raspberrypi postfix/pickup[1809]: BA9A76059: uid=0 from=<root>
Jul 13 08:12:16 raspberrypi postfix/cleanup[1952]: BA9A76059: message-id=<20190713061216.BA9A76059@raspberrypi.localdomain>
Jul 13 08:12:16 raspberrypi postfix/qmgr[1638]: BA9A76059: from=<root@raspberrypi.localdomain>, size=435, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 13 08:12:16 raspberrypi postfix/error[1954]: BA9A76059: to=<root@raspberrypi.localdomain>, orig_to=<root>, relay=none, delay=0.09, delays=0.04/0.03/0/0.02, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (raspberrypi.localdomain)
Jul 13 08:12:16 raspberrypi postfix/cleanup[1952]: CBF576061: message-id=<20190713061216.CBF576061@raspberrypi.localdomain>
Jul 13 08:12:16 raspberrypi postfix/bounce[1955]: BA9A76059: sender non-delivery notification: CBF576061
Jul 13 08:12:16 raspberrypi postfix/qmgr[1638]: CBF576061: from=<>, size=2447, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 13 08:12:16 raspberrypi postfix/qmgr[1638]: BA9A76059: removed
Jul 13 08:12:16 raspberrypi postfix/error[1954]: CBF576061: to=<root@raspberrypi.localdomain>, relay=none, delay=0, delays=0/0/0/0, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (raspberrypi.localdomain)
Jul 13 08:12:16 raspberrypi postfix/qmgr[1638]: CBF576061: removed
```

I'd be grateful for any help

Answer (score 0):

The solution are following lines in /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
myhostname = localhost
mydomain = localdomain
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
inet_interfaces = $myhostname, localhost
mynetworks_style = host
default_transport = error: outside mail is not deliverable
```

restart postfix service

```sh
root@raspberrypi:~# systemctl restart postfix.service
```

voila

```
root@raspberrypi:~# echo Test | mail -s test root
root@raspberrypi:~# mail
Mail version 8.1.2 01/15/2001.  Type ? for help.
"/var/mail/root": 1 message 1 new
>N  1 root@localhost.lo  Sat Jul 13 15:55   17/547   test
```